# Trouble with Json in kibana

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I'm using Kibana to visualise some key data about my sports team, I have a spreadsheet that is updated, saved as a CSV and then converted to json.

The CSV file will upload successfully:

```
Player,Total
Reiss,18
Ethan,14
Josh,12
Callum,10
Mckenze,9
Khalid,4
Kevin,8
Colm,5
Dan,5
Pharrell,1
```

But when I convert that to JSON I keep getting an error message;

[image]

The json format is:

```
[
 {
   "Player": "Reiss",
   "Total": 18
 },
 {
   "Player": "Ethan",
   "Total": 14
 },
 {
   "Player": "Josh",
   "Total": 12
 },
 {
   "Player": "Callum",
   "Total": 10
 },
 {
   "Player": "Mckenze",
   "Total": 9
 },
 {
   "Player": "Khalid",
   "Total": 4
 },
 {
   "Player": "Kevin",
   "Total": 8
 },
 {
   "Player": "Colm",
   "Total": 5
 },
 {
   "Player": "Dan",
   "Total": 5
 },
 {
   "Player": "Pharrel",
   "Total": 1
 }
]
```

Comment: "Only highly structured formats like CSV and NDJSON are accepted without timestamps.". https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/63526#issuecomment-613725348

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly it. I'm not sure why ELK makes that more clear for simple data that doesn't need any timestamps against it.

Comment: Also ndjson files must have each record on a line separated by newlines, yours is fully formatted, which won't work, see the second explanation message